# React prepend item to list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prepend

I'm trying to prepend an item to a list:

```
addPersonHandler = () => {
    const newPerson = {
          id: "new",
          edit: true,        
          name: "",
          dni: "",
          onDelete: this.discardHandler
        };

    // I want to prepend the new person to the people list.
    this.setState({addingPerson: true, people: {[newPerson].concat(this.state.people)});
}
```

But it ALWAYS renders LAST!

```
<ul>
    People.map((p, i) => {
      return <li key={p.id}>
        <Person 
          id={p.id} 
          name={p.name} 
          dni={p.dni} 
          onDelete={p.id=="new"? this.discardHandler: this.deleteHandler}
          edit={p.edit}         
          />
      </li>
    });    
</ul>
```

I really don't know why if I'm adding it to the beginning of the list it is rendering last...

Comment: `people: {[newPerson].concat(this.state.people)}` You've got that wrapped in curly brackets. Is that in the actual code, or a typo when posting? Also, it looks like all new persons will get an identical id; is that intentional?

Comment: use unique value for `key` and all should be fine

Answer (score 4):

You can use a spread on original array and remove the `{}` wrapping new array

```
this.setState({addingPerson: true, people: [newPerson, ...this.state.people]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [the `unshift()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), which you can use to prepend one or more elements to the `people` array.

Keep in mind that `unshift()` method mutates the array that it's called on:

```
addPersonHandler = () => {

    const newPerson = {
          id: "new",
          edit: true,        
          name: "",
          dni: "",
          onDelete: this.discardHandler
        };


       // Get people array from current state
       const people = this.state.people;

       // Prepends the newPerson to the start of people array
       people.unshift(newPerson);

       // Return the updated state to your component for re-render
       this.setState({ addingPerson : true, people : people });
}
```

Comment: What difference does callback make...still mutating original inside it? Using slice() or  spread would prevent the mutation of original

Comment: You're right - no value added here with `setState(callback)` based approach. Thanks for the suggested improvement :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, take state in one new array variable and push new object into it, finally update the state.

```
  addPersonHandler = () => {
      const newPerson = {
        id: "new",
        edit: true,
        name: "",
        dni: "",
        onDelete: this.discardHandler
      };

      let pplArr = this.state.people;
      pplArr.push(newPerson);
      this.setState({ addingPerson: true, people: pplArr });
    };
```

Comment: generally better practice not to mutate state directly

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
          <Person 
          id={p.id} 
          name={p.name} 
          dni={p.dni} 
          onDelete={p.id=="new"? this.discardHandler: this.deleteHandler}
          edit={p.edit}         
          />
    People.map((p, i) => {
      return <li key={p.id}>

      </li>
    });    
</ul>
```